# How to close an android app from my phone after running from eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to learn android development but after running my app through my phone it runs fine, but I can't close it. It doesn't even appear as a running app under apps on my phone settings. It doesn't appear anywhere on my phone but it is running. There doesn't seem to be any kind of stop button in eclipse.

How do I close the app on my phone/eclipse cleanly so I can carry on editing and re-run it?

The only thing I can think of is just unplugging the USB cable but I am afraid of breaking things. ADB feels fragile enough as it is.

I have searched a few answers on this site but they seem to be talking about something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down the home key until a list of running apps appears.  Then just swipe it away :)

If you're truly interested in making an app go away completely then there's a FANTASTIC app called DevDrawer (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.owentech.DevDrawer) that allows you to put package names of apps in it that you're currently developing.  Trust me when I tell you that it will save you a LOT of time.

Comment: With my phone there's a button next to home which does this (xperia t). It seems a combination of this and Gustek's answer is needed to make this work. Do any files get left on my phone anywhere after testing an app that I might want to clean up afterwards?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html). Select process representing Your app on the list in top left window and click stop button You will see above.

Comment: Thank you this seems to work but then I still have to swipe the app closed on the phone as well. Does running an android app on a phone to test leave behind any junk files I'd want to delete after?

Comment: To be honest I never paid attention if debugging mode create any extra files. My guess would be that there is nothing left but I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you just re-install the app after some code change, it should re-run...even if you have the app open on your phone!

Comment: It gives me an error and doesn't re-run it if I don't close it. "ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front"

Comment: This means no code changes have been made. If you change your code and re-run, it will re-launch.